# Matlab: Linearizing Simulink model and getting linearized transfer function?

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, transfer

I want to determine the linearized transfer function from a non-linear system made in Simulink. I can see that it should be possible to use the `linmod` function in Matlab but when I try this

```
[num,den]=linmod('sys')
```

I'm not getting the numerator and denominator but instead the state space matrix etc. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Try the function `balred` instead: [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/control/ref/balred.html)

> `rsys = balred(sys,ORDERS)` computes a reduced-order approximation `rsys`
>   of the LTI model `sys`. The desired order (number of states) for `rsys` is
>   specified by ORDERS. You can try multiple orders at once by setting
>   ORDERS to a vector of integers, in which case `rsys` is a vector of
>   reduced-order models. balred uses implicit balancing techniques to
>   compute the reduced- order approximation `rsys`.

**example:**

```
Q = tf([1 2 3 4 5],[5 4 3 2 1])

Q =

   s^4 + 2 s^3 + 3 s^2 + 4 s + 5
  -------------------------------
  5 s^4 + 4 s^3 + 3 s^2 + 2 s + 1
```

---

```
Q_lin = balred(Q,2)

Q_lin =

  3.276 s^2 - 2.06 s + 2.394
  --------------------------
   s^2 - 0.2757 s + 0.4789
```

---

```
balred(Q,1)
```

is not working for my example, as there are 2 unstable poles, but it may works for your system.

Answer (score 2):

[`linmod`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/linmod.html) always returns a state-space representation (see documentation). Use [`tf`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/tf.html) to convert your stae-space representation to a transfer function:

> **Conversion to Transfer Function**
>
> `tfsys = tf(sys)` converts the dynamic
>   system model `sys` to transfer function form. The output `tfsys` is a `tf`
>   model object representing `sys` expressed as a transfer function.

BTW, if you have Simulink Control Design, a better alternative to `linmod` is [`linearize`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/slcontrol/ug/linearize.html).